# django issue in html as images are loading as zoom images

Tags: django

I am facing a weird problem, till yesterday the page was loading properly but after 2 days. the page is loading with images being zoomed.. (i.e. actual image size ) unable to figure out.

```
main.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
           <title>Ecom</title>

           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />

           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var user = '{{request.user}}'

           function getToken(name) {
                let cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                    return cookieValue;
            }
           const csrftoken = getToken('csrftoken');

           function getCookie(name) {

             var cookieArr = document.cookie.split(";");

             for (var i = 0; i < cookieArr.length; i++)  {
                  var cookiePair = cookieArr[i].split("=");
                  console.log('cookiePair:',cookiePair);
                  if(name==cookiePair[0].trim()) {
                     return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
                   }
              }

              return null;
          }
          var cart = JSON.parse(getCookie('cart'))
          if(cart == undefined) {
              cart = {}
              console.log('Cart was created');
              document.cookie = 'cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) +";domain=;path=/"
           }

          console.log('Cart:',cart);
        </script>
     </head>
     <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'store' %}">Ecom</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'store' %}">Store <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
        <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
           <a href="#"class="btn btn-warning">Login</a>
           <a href="{% url 'cart' %}">
                <img id="cart-icon" src="{% static 'images/cart.png' %}">
            </a>
            <p id="cart-total">{{cartItems}}</p>
        </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}

         {% endblock content %}
            <br>
              <nav aria-label="...">
                {%if page.paginator %}
                 <ul class="pagination">
                   {%if NoOfProducts > 6 %}
                    <li class="page-item {% if not prev_page_url %} disabled {% endif %} ">

                      <a class="page-link" href="{{ prev_page_url }}" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Previous</a>
                    </li>

                    {% for n in page.paginator.page_range %}

                       {% if page.number == n %}
                            <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                               <a class="page-link" href=="?page={{n}}">{{n}}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>

                       {% elif n > page.number|add:-3 and n < page.number|add:3  %}
                            <li class="page_item">
                              <a class="page-link" href ="?page={{n}}">{{n}}</a>

                           </li>
                       {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}

                    <li class="page-item {% if not next_page_url %} disabled {% endif %} ">
                      <a class="page-link" href="{{next_page_url}}">Next</a>
                    </li>
                   {% endif %}
                  </ul>
                {% endif %}
              </nav>

     </div>



     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
body{
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    color:hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
}

.box-element{
    box-shadow:hsl(0, 0%, 80%) 0 0 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.thumbnail{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -3px 5px -2px rgba(214,214,214,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px -3px 5px -2px rgba(214,214,214,1);
    box-shadow: -1px -3px 5px -2px rgba(214,214,214,1);
}

.product{
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.bg-dark{
    background-color: #4f868c!important;
}

#cart-icon{
    width:25px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

#cart-total{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.col-lg-4, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-12{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn{
    border-radius: 0;
}

.row-image{
    width: 100px;
}

.form-field{
    width:250px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

.cart-row{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-stretch;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ececec;

}

.quantity{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-right:10px;


}

.chg-quantity{
    width: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    transition:.1s;
}

.chg-quantity:hover{
    opacity: .6;
}


.hidden{
    display: none!important;
}
```

**Output:**
[image: Images Being zoom]

Can someone help me how to resolve the issue? what setting needs to change thus enable to load correct image sizes .. ( only the problem facing the size of the images... )

Thank you very much

Comment: it was an caching issue got an answer from one of SO forums  [  Maybe a caching issue, try press F5 while holding shift button ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

caching issue, try press F5 while holding shift button and it solved the problem